# Авто-перезапуск завершившихся приложений через Screen

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, mono, gnu-screen

Привет всем! Запускаю приложение написанное на c# через mono, которое крутится в screen. Ubuntu.

Бывает приложение дает сбой и выключается, соответственно сессия в screen удаляется.

Есть ли вариант, чтобы та сессия которая завершилась, автоматически перезапустилась, как допустим через forever запускать node js скрипты? (при сбое, сессия в forever автоматически перезапускается с параметрами запуска).

Comment: А почему приложение запускается через screen?  Какую задачу это решает? И как именно вы его запускаете?

Comment: Нужно чтобы оно крутилось круглосуточно. Запускаю так: screen -dmLS app mono /var/www/1.exe user pass > /var/www/_log.txt

Comment: Перефразирую вопрос, почему screen, а не runit, upstart, systemd, etc?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, знаком только со screen =)

Comment: Понял. В Ubuntu для управления демонами используется Upstart. Ваша программа по сути демон и будет удобно использовать аналогичный способ управления. Но вы так же посмотрите и на другие - runit, monit. Может они вам больше понравится.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, они не перешли на systemd?!

Comment: @0andriy перешли вроде, но upstart по моему поддерживают. Я поэтому и посоветовал посмотреть на другие системы.

Comment: Для таких случаев можно использовать supervisor

Comment: @5f0f5 поможете с запуском моего приложения программно?

Comment: Вот хорошая интструкция https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-upravlenie-supervisor-na-servere-ubuntu-i-debian/

Comment: Тут писали про supervisor, что весьма хорошо. Можете даже написать unit для systemd и "интегрировать" в систему свою службу.

Answer (score 1):

можно вашу программу запускать в бесконечном цикле.

т.е., вместо (к примеру)

```
$ screen date
```

где *gnu/screen* завершится сразу же, потому что программа *date* выведет текущую дату и вернёт управление, можно написать так:

```
$ screen bash -c 'while :; date; sleep 2; done'
```

текущие дата и время будут выводиться бесконечно (*sleep* я вставил, чтобы не так быстро информация поступала).

Comment: т.е. нужно будет запускать так? : screen bash -cdmLS app 'while :; mono /var/www/1.exe user pass > /var/www/_log.txt; sleep 2; done'

Comment: и если я захочу остановить вручную программу, она остановится? :D

Comment: 1. да, можно так. 2. нажмёте `ctrl+c` (лучше сразу несколько раз подряд) — и цикл завершится, а, следовательно, и сеанс *screen*-а.

Comment: завершаю вот так: screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill

Comment: за что отвечает команда -c? и как я понимаю bash - это название для сессии?

Comment: *bash* — это программа. её можно вызвать с опцией `-c строка`, тогда программа выполнит команды, перечисленные в строке, и завершит работу. см. `$ man bash`.

Comment: не получилось... делаю я это все через node js: exec. Сейчас мой запуск выглядит так: exec('screen -dmLS [' + i + ']:name_' + user + ':' + pass + '_' + server + '_' + id + ' mono /var/www/text.exe ' + user + ' ' + pass + ' ' + server + ' ' + id + ' > /var/www/' + [i] + '_log.txt'); Поможете?

Comment: я думаю, вы лучше меня разбираетесь в синтаксисе js. задавайте новый вопрос, но уже про то, как правильно всё это записать, учитывая необходимость кавычек (одинарных или двойных — в данном случае безразлично) в команде `bash -c "строка"`

Comment: Разберемся.. тогда вопрос, нужно ли "-c" указывать вместе с параметрами screen " -dmLS"? И как их правильно указать? Я с Js'ом то разберусь, вот разобраться бы как записать то вообще =)

Comment: у вас программе *screen* передаётся вызов программы *mono* с аргументами. вместо программы *mono* я и предлагаю запускать программу *bash* с аргументами.

Comment: т.е. автоматически будет запущено через mono?

Comment: не понял вашего последнего вопроса.

Comment: ну если я не использую mono, а bash, запускаться то мое приложение будет?